# Exchange 2003 OWA galfind only returning HTML response

Tags: exchange-server, webdav, outlook-web-app

I've got a routine that queries galfind and for most situations it returns the expected XML response after issuing a basic GET. I'm trying it out now on an older (Exchange 2003) server and the galfind GET will only return the HTML search form.  The query response data returns correctly along with the form content but it'd be nice to get it in XML format.  So two related questions:

1. Does OWA in Exchange 2003 support XML responses for galfind?
2. If so, how does one either modify the HTTP request or configure the server to retrieve the XML formatted response from a galfind query?

Here's an example GET request I've been playing with:

> GET
>
> http://mail.mydomain.com/exchange/administrator@mydomain.com/?cmd=galfind&dn=C
>
> HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
>
> Accept: text/xml
>
> Authorization: Basic
>
> Host: mail.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Adding "MSIE 6.0" to the User-Agent seems to allow you to toggle over to an XML formatted response, e.g.

> GET
>
> http://mail.mydomain.com/exchange/administrator@mydomain.com/?cmd=galfind&dn=C
>
> HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (**MSIE 6.0;** Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
>
> Accept: text/xml
>
> Authorization: Basic
>
> Host: mail.mydomain.com